# homomorpic encryption

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

I am doing project k-nearest neighbor classification over semantically secure encrypted relational data I have doubt for in smin algorithm in

1)Li ← Wi ∗ Φir′; ri′ ∈R ZN

this line it the out put is

original output
r
r
1
r
r
r

my output
-1
-1
1
r
r
r
please help how to get this output
hint:
After this, P1 computes L by combining Φ and W.
More precisely, P1 computes Li = Wi ∗ Φ
r
′
i
i
, where
r
′
i
is a random number in ZN . The observation here
is if ∃ an index j such that Φj = Epk(0), denoting
the first flip in the bits of u and v, then Wj stores
the corresponding desired information, i.e., whether
uj > vj or vj > uj in encrypted form